# Refering to specific rows in database without using Column info, in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

If i had a mySQL database with the following columns

```
id       firstname      lastname         email              message
1        bob              billy         blah@blah.com         hi
2        bobby            gen           bleh@blah.com          bye
3        bobbo            rilly         blarh@blah.com         cry
.
.
.
```

where id was the autoincrementing column and therefore functioning as the primary key. How would I query my database to remove a specific row?

I thought of using SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1;
But, i cant use that, since if i delete a row, along goes the id, and using it as a mark of position would be pointless, since the next entry would make a gap.

For example if i removed the 2nd row from the above table then:

```
id     firstname        lastname         email              message
1        bob              billy         blah@blah.com         hi
3        bobbo            rilly         blarh@blah.com         cry
.
.
.
```

would be the result. And if i added a new row to the supposed table then:

```
id      firstname       lastname        email               message
1        bob              billy         blah@blah.com         hi
3        bobbo            rilly         blarh@blah.com         cry
4        sam              ham            bee@nooo.com         why
.
.
.
```

would be the result, which as stated before, doesn't allow me to specify which row(first, second, third, and so on) to remove,without acutally looking at the database, since the count is messed up. Any ideas on how to do this? I am bad at coding, so detailed explanations would help tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option establishing a row number using `user-defined variables`:

```
delete from yourtable
where id = (
  select id from (
    select id, @rn:=@rn+1 rn
    from yourtable, (select @rn:=0) t
    order by id
    ) t
  where rn = 2)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24fdd/1)

This uses row 2 (`where rn = 2`).  Change the `where` criteria to select a different row.

Comment: I found out that sgeddes worked for me as i wanted, i avoided it at first because it confused me, but im glad i tried it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what is the 2nd row in your table, you could do the following :

`select * from myTable limit 1,1`

To clarify `LIMIT X, Y` :

Where X => From what row should it start

Where Y => Maximum number of rows to returns.

So in the previous example, it means start at position 1 and returns me 1. Please note, that the position are zero-indexed : position 1 means 2nd row, position 0 means 1st row. This will return one single result that is the 2nd row of your table.

Keep in mind that this depends on the ordering of the query. By default, Mysql will use the auto-incremental primary key as the natural order. In your case, that means, Mysql is doing a `ORDER by id DESC` by default.

If you change the ordering, obviously, you may get another row returned by the previous query.

Any reason, why in your application you don't use the `id` of the table as the parameter to determine what row to delete instead of its position in the outputted table ? That way, you would not need to do a select before doing your delete and that would make the whole thing simpler.

Comment: The reason why i don't use the id of the table as the parameter to determine what row to delete instead of its position in the outputted table is something i cant really explain. I cant use the id because wouldnt i have to look up what the id was refering to in each case?     With your way can i not just use "general positions"?

Comment: When you are rendering the table, you should have the `id` of each row, right ? Assuming that you are providing some kind of a link to delete a row, the link could be generated using the `id` as a parameter (e.g. `"?action=delete&id=" . $row['id']`).

Comment: I dont really understand your last comment, i am not very good at coding. What i want to do is use a php mysql query to delete data from a specific position in a table.      $queryTwo = "DELETE FROM MyGuests WHERE type = 'firstname' ORDER BY id DESC limit 3,3"; is what i tried to use but it didnt work.

Comment: You can't use LIMIT clause with a delete. If you want to do it with one single query, then sgeddes gave you the right answer.